# php fopen path error

Tags: php, path, fopen

I'm trying to provide the path in PHP to download the file from Gmail and save it inside desktop folder name "Attachment"

```
$fp = fopen('C:\\Users\\Akash Atri\\Desktop\\Attachment' . $email_number . "-" . $filename, "w+")
```

But file saved to desktop not inside  "Attachment" folder

Also tried,

```
$fp = fopen('C:\\Users\\Akash Atri\\Desktop\\Attachment\\' . $email_number . "-" . $filename, "w+")
```

but this also saving file inside desktop

Please help me out!!!

Comment: \\\ looks odd to use for escaping

Comment: Sooo many backslashes....

Comment: I think 2 `\\` are enough

Comment: There are never too many backlashes!

Comment: Actually  when I'm posting the question Stackoverflow interface showing two backslashes as 1 so I put three backslashes so it will be show as 2 backslashes

Comment: Actually their is no error in code syntax but then also files are not going inside attachment folder,they are downloaded inside desktop folder